# QUICKBASE PHP SDK add_record returns blank response

Tags: php, sdk, quickbase

I was recently brought on by a company that uses Quickbase. They have limited systems in place to talk to the Quickbase application, so I am trying to incorporate the PHP SDK in order to add/edit records in Quickbase using a front end designed by myself so customers can submit a form from the web into Quickbase.

I'm coming across a problem right away trying to get the SDK to even respond with something other than an error. Currently it doesn't respond with anything when trying to add a record.

I keep reading that a recent (~2-3 years ago) change has caused this to be a bit difficult to use.

below is my codesnippet from a php page called "addnewcustomer.php"

```
 include_once('quickbase.php');

 //my PHP SDK Options located inside quickbase.php
var $user_name   = 'username';  // QuickBase user who will access the QuickBase
var $passwd      = 'pw';    // Password of this user
var $db_id       = 'dbid';  // Table/Database ID of the QuickBase being accessed
var $app_token   = 'my app token';
var $xml         = true;
var $user_id     = '';
var $qb_site     = "www.mycompany.quickbase.com";
var $qb_ssl      = "https://www.mycompany.quickbase.com/db/";
var $ticketHours = 12;

 $quickbase = new QuickBase('myusername', 'mypw', true, "dbid", "token", "realm", hour);  

$fields = array(
        array(
            'fid'   => '148',
            'value' => $agentid), //agentid

        array(
            'fid'   => '15',
            'value' => $city), //city
        array(
            'fid'   => '16',
            'value' => $state), //state
        array(
            'fid'   => '14',
            'value' => $address), //address
        array(
            'fid'   => '524',
            'value' => $apt), //apt #
        array(
            'fid'   => '17',
            'value' => $zip), //zip code
        array(
            'fid'   => '33',
            'value' => $rentown), //rent/own
        array(
            'fid'   => '28',
            'value' => $first), //first name
        array(
            'fid'   => '29',
            'value' => $last), //last name
        array(
            'fid'   => '21',
            'value' => $email), //email
        array(
            'fid'   => '18',
            'value' => $phone) //phone
            );

$quickbase->add_record($fields);
```

It currently responds with nothing, ie. blank response. If I change the realm with something inaccurate I get an error of "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'", which makes me think I have everything setup correctly.

What should a successful entry return? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The add_record method should be returning an XML object.  If you capture that object, you can check it to see if the API call was successful or if an error was returned.  So, if you change your code to:

```
$results = $quickbase->add_record($fields);
print_r($results);
```

You'll get something you can understand.  It's inelegant, but it will show you quickly if you're getting a response and if that response is an error.  You should see something like this on success:

> ```
> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [action] => API_AddRecord [errcode] => 0 [errtext] => No error [rid] => 81 [update_id] => 1436476140453 )
> ```